# Сравнение типов значений с null

Tags: c#, null

Самый простой пример - метод `Add()` класса `Dictionary<TKey, V>`. При добавлении ключа, проверяется равен ли он `null` и для этого параметр `key` приводится к `object` на тот вариант, если `TKey` значимый тип. Однако меня интересует целесообразность упаковки valueType, ведь условие `if(key == null){}` будет работать исправно в любом случае.

Т. о. если я правильно понимаю, приведение к `object` нужно лишь для того чтобы не получить предупреждение?

upd.
Скит пишет

```
int i = 5; 
if (i == null) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine ("Never going to happen"); 
}
```

> Компилятор С# выдаст для этого кода
> предупреждение, но вас может удивить,
> что он  допустим вообще. Что же здесь
> происходит, действительно ли
> компилятор видит   выражение int в
> левой стороне оператора ==, видит
> значение null в правой стороне и
> знает,  что нужно неявное
> преобразование в тип int? для каждого
> из них. Поскольку сравнения  между
> двумя значениями типа int? совершенно
> допустимы, код не вызывает ошибки, только предупреждение.

В итоге, если мы упакуем значение вот так:

```
int i = 5; 
if ((object)i == null) 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine ("Never going to happen"); 
}
```

То получим новый объект в куче, которого в принципе могло бы и не быть, если просто сравнивать значения.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, зачем вы приводите значение к object в generic-коллекции.

Comment: @Flammable, я видимо плохо сформулировал вопрос. Это не я привожу значение к object в generic-коллекциях, значение приводится в методе Insert, который вызывается из метода Add коллекции System.Dictionary<T, V>
private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
{
    if ((object) key == null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
...

Comment: Либо шутки декомпилятора, либо костыль для устранения предупреждений. Хотя во втором случае разумнее использовать `#pragma warning disable`.

Comment: Похоже на шутки декомпилятора, поскольку в `reference source` используется [обычная проверка `if (key == null)`.](http://goo.gl/tgThZ)

Comment: всё-таки там есть box, вот что показал ildasm

  IL_0000:  ldarg.1

  IL_0001:  box        !TKey

  IL_0006:  brtrue.s   IL_000e

  IL_0008:  ldc.i4.5

  IL_0009:  call       void 
System.ThrowHelper::ThrowArgumentNullException(valuetype System.ExceptionArgument)

Comment: Думаю, что упаковка значения в объект и проверка выкинется JIT-компилятором (т.к. основные оптимизации происходят там).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Немного подробностей - несмотря на то, что в исходниках действительно нет `(object)`, оно есть в IL.

```
public static void Test<T>(T param)
{
    if (param == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Never going to happen");
    }
}
```

после компиляции (в release!) в IL превращается в

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Test<T>(!!T param) cil managed
{
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  box        !!T <----
  IL_0006:  brtrue.s   IL_0012
  IL_0008:  ldstr      "Never going to happen"
  IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method Program::Test
```

Обратите внимание, что никаких вызовов `==` уже нет. Значение в стеке - адрес объекта в памяти - просто сравнивается с 0.

Более того, boxing и проверка на null есть и после прохода JIT по коду при запуске под отладчиком:

```
            Test(5);
01212640  mov         ecx,5  
01212645  call        dword ptr ds:[5191C7Ch]  

----

        if (param == null)
01212678  push        ebp  
01212679  mov         ebp,esp  
0121267B  sub         esp,8  
0121267E  xor         eax,eax  
01212680  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
01212683  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx  
01212686  cmp         dword ptr ds:[5190B94h],0  
0121268D  je          01212694  
0121268F  call        7431C310  
01212694  mov         ecx,73273B04h  
01212699  call        01182100  
0121269E  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax  
012126A1  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
012126A4  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4]  
012126A7  mov         dword ptr [eax+4],edx  
012126AA  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
012126AD  test        eax,eax  
012126AF  jne         012126BC  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Never going to happen");
012126B1  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[3D621F4h]  
012126B7  call        731A023C  
        }
    }
012126BC  nop  
        }
    }
012126BD  mov         esp,ebp  
012126BF  pop         ebp  
012126C0  ret
```

а вот запуск без отладчика полностью меняет картину. Код вида

```
Debugger.Launch();
Test(5);
Test("test");
```

на самом деле превращается в

```
            Debugger.Launch();
041D0050  push        ebp  
041D0051  mov         ebp,esp  
041D0053  call        7386868C  
            Test("test");
01260058  cmp         dword ptr ds:[3C82188h],0  <-- это заинлайненный if
0126005F  jne         01260076  
01260061  call        731A0258
```

Нет никакого `box`. Нет if. Нет даже ни одного вызова `Test`. Вызов с `5` удален целиком. Вызов с `string test` - заинлайнен.

Не заморачивайтесь и дайте JIT делать свою работу. И да, компилируйте Production сборки как Release, а не как Debug. Это сокращает жизнь переменных - и продлевает жизнь разработчика.

Comment: Угу. Я как-то замерял скорость тестового кода в debug/release режимах, и под отладчиком/без него. Переход в release увеличивал скорость пробега вдвое (что с отладчиком, что без). И отсутствие отладчика увеличивало скорость пробега тоже примерно вдвое (что в debug, что в release-режиме)

Comment: Мораль: смотрите на release-код вне отладчика.

Comment: @VladD еще веселее - отсутствие отладчика включает некоторые оптимизации, которых вообще как бы нет в C#. Tail Recursion, например.

Comment: Угу. Потому что в отладчике это достаточно трудно будет визуализировать так, чтобы юзеры поняли. И элиминация переманных туда же. И отсутствие проверок, которые оптимизатор сообразил, что можно выкинуть.

Comment: Спасибо, было очень интересно прочитать это пояснение.
А если в исходники добавить явное приведение к object, ситуация изменится?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, IL будет точно таким же.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы действительно хотите сравнить с `null`, то сравнивайте на здоровье. Это предупреждение существует, так как подобное сравнение часто ошибочно.

Будете ли вы приводить к `object` или сравнивать просто так — наверняка не имеет значения, потому что JIT-компилятор выкинет избыточные сравнения с `null` для value-типов.

В [исходнике CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/cbf46fb0b6a0b209ed1caf4a680910b383e68cba/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L294) простое сравнение:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
    if( key == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Т. о. если я правильно понимаю, приведение к object нужно лишь для того чтобы не получить предупреждение?

Подозреваю, что неправильно. Как уже написали, в исходниках этого приведения нет.

Я думаю, что оно появляется в скомпилированном варианте в силу того, что generic-методы компилируются на основе информации, которая известна при компиляции, а не при запуске. Соответственно, там дан только generic-тип `TKey`, на который не накладывается никаких ограничений. Всё, что знает компилятор, что это некоторый `object`. Дальше он наталкивается на использование оператора `==`, единственная применимая перегрузка которого принимает два объекта `object`. Чтобы вызвать этот оператор, key неявно приводится компилятором к `object`.

Кстати, весьма вероятно, что jit-компилятор всё равно оптимизирует эту штуку, как происходит с кастом в `IEnumerable` при указании типа переменной в linq-запросе.

PS: Это только мои представления о происходящем, я не проверял, действительно ли всё происходит именно так.